# Как мутировать текст?

Tags: текст, разметка, семантика

**Задача** генерировать некое количество похожих по содержанию, но не совпадающих 1:1 коротких текстов – например, постов в соц. сети.

Предполагаю, что будет делаться шаблон с местами, куда подставляются либо формы слова в зависимости от пола «автора», либо один из синонимов, случайно.

**Псевдокод:**

```
{gender:Решил|решила} {random:попробовать|испытать|потестить} 
{random:новый сервис|новую примочку} для моих задач.
```

Если усложнять, понадобятся кросс-связи для родов-падежей выбранных вариантов в разных частях предложения. Глобальные и локальные переменные. Целый ЯП?

**Вопрос:** существует ли стандартный подход к такой задаче (как называется такая задача), есть ли язык разметки, подходящий для описания таких шаблонов?

---

**Upd.** Если мечтать, идеально и «правильно» было бы просто подать единственный вариант текста на вход. И иметь движок, способный адекватно оценить смысл, разложить на элементы и самостоятельно предложить замены исходя из заданных допусков. Напр. *пол* фиксировать параметром, упомянутые *цвета* не менять, упомянутые *имена художников* менять в рамках одного художественного стиля и исторической эпохи (ладно, это уже высший пилотаж был бы : )

Comment: Не скромный вопрос - не попытка ли здесь повторить вот этот продукт:  [SeoGenerator](http://seogenerator.ru/tools/). Особенно похожа на вашу задачу его генератор.

Comment: Ну вот не понимаю, в чём проблема взять и реализовать. Если бы мне было надо, я бы так и поступил.

Comment: @Ruslan задача другая, хотя принцип чем-то похож. Изучу, спасибо!

Comment: @Qwertiy ваш комментарий не уточняет и не прибавляет ценности вопросу.

Answer (score 1):

Никогда этим не занимался, но знаю что обычно для этого используют цепи Маркова. [Информация для размышления](http://eax.me/haskell-text-gen/).

[Второй источник пищи к размышлению](http://aot.ru/docs/sokirko/sokirko-candid-5.html). Описывается система перевода, общий принцип работы которой сводится к последовательности преобразований: *язык 1*`->`*анализ*`->`*семантическое описание*`->`*генерация*`->`*язык 2*. Как вы понимаете у вас на входе и на выходе должен быть один и тот же язык, плюс потребуется в семантическом описании подставлять синонимы в разных комбинациях. Можно сделать более простой вариант который содержал бы только второй этап - генерацию.

Вообще к чему я это все, а к тому что стоит поискать переводчики с открытым кодом реализующими приведенный принцип.  Кстати сам Сокирко со товарищи выложил [свои наработки](http://sourceforge.net/projects/seman/) под GPL. Это не система перевода а система анализа, но главное там есть инструменты для работы с семантическими описаниями.

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Ищу, читаю.

Comment: Upd. пока нашел только примеры генерации **бессмысленного** текста, повторяющего частотное распределение слов исходного. Для сео-мусора, может, и вариант. Но у меня другая задача – сохранить смысл и читаемость.

Comment: Интересный опыт на php с исходниками по генерации «синтаксически правильного» текста: программа [Geniot](http://nickolay.info/php/geniot.html)

Answer (score 1):

Ну предположим, так (работает в Firefox актуальной версии):

```
var processors = {
  gender(options, m, w) {
    return options.gender === 'm' ? m : w;
  },
  random(options, ...a) {
    return a[Math.random() * a.length | 0];
  }
};

function generate(template, options) {
  return template.replace(/\{(\w+):(.*?)\}/g, function (match, key, str) {
    return processors[key] ? processors[key].apply(null, [options].concat(str.match(/(\\[{}|\\]|[^|])+/g))) : match;
  });
}

var template = "{gender:Решил|Решила} {random:попробовать|испытать|потестить} \n\
{random:новый сервис|новую примочку} для моих задач."

for (var q=0; q<10; ++q)
  console.log(generate(template, { gender: 'mw'[q&1] }));
```

Вроде сюда можно добавить любую желаемую логику.

Comment: дерево зависимостей может ветвиться глубже. Напр., в зависимости от случайно выбранного варианта, далее случайно выбирать из разных массивов: `{rand:дыню|укроп}, чей {rand:сладкий|спелый||ароматный|свежий} вкус...`